# AE/AF lock on iPhone - turn off display?

Tags: iphone, video, quicktime

I'm using an iPhone as a camera source via USB to record video using Quicktime on my Macbook.  I want to use AE/AF Lock, but when I do, the recorded video will show the yellow square and AE/AF lock message.  The only way to disable it is to unlock AE/AF.

Does anyone know of a way to keep it locked, without displaying the message and square on screen?

Thanks

Comment: Is there an issue with recording directly on the phone and moving to the Mac (storage on phone, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  The issue is I'm trying to sync two or more sources live, rather than record and then transfer from phone to computer.  I can't see a way to get rid of the display, so I might have to record onto the phone.  Storage could become an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using an app called OBS camera in combination with OBS studio.  It has many manual settings which override the regular phone camera, and also lets you easily set up multiple ios cameras.  It even has a web-based remote control feature.

So I set me AE/AF manually and this stops the autofocus from appearing in the video.

I'm sure there must be other camera apps that do similar things.